# node mongo : update multiple arrays at same time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following document :

```
{
  name:"myDoc",
  array1:['a','b'],
  array2:['a','b'],
  array3:['a','b']
}
```

I would like to add in the same update operation, the value "c" to the 3 arrays. I know how to do it with 3 separate steps :

```
db.collection('myCollection').updateMany(
{name:'myDoc'},
  {$addToSet: { array1:"c" }}
)
```

and do that 3 times, but I want to know if its possible to do the 3 additions in one single update.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just specify all sets you want to update:

```
db.collection('myCollection')
  .updateMany(
     {name:'myDoc'},
     {$addToSet: { 
          array1:"c",  
          array2:"c",
          array3:"c" }
})
```

Example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yHqzi_lEaA0